# Unable to run Python Selenium Tests on Self Hosted Azure VM

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to execute the Selenium test in my self hosted VM from Azure pipelines. I am getting below error message.

##[error]Version spec 3.8 for architecture x64 did not match any version in Agent.ToolsDirectory.
[image: pipelines]

Below is my Yaml

```
trigger:
- main

pool: default strategy:   matrix:
    Python38:
      python.version: '3.8'
      addToPath: true

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0   inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'   displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt   displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    pip install pytest-azurepipelines
    pytest tests\test_smoke\test_suite_SmokeTest.py -s -v --browser Chrome --html=report.html --reruns 2   displayName: 'pytest'

- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2   inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '8801f21d-f4e9-4b65-b01e-68baf825747c'
    definition: '5'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
```

---

I have configured the agent in my VM. I have also installed the python 3.8.6 in VM and configured the python path for it.
[image: python_path]
[image: agent_running]

Comment: For the Ubuntu setup see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64212888/azure-self-hosted-agent-to-run-pytest/66026204#66026204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unable to run Python Selenium Tests on Self Hosted Azure VM

To use this task on the private agent, we need to **add the desired Python version to the tool cache on the self-hosted agent** in order for the task to use it.

Normally the tool cache is located under the _work/_tool directory of the agent or you could use the command line task to echo the variable `$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)` to get the path.

Then, under that directory, create the following directory structure based off of your Python version:

```
$AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY/
    Python/
        {version number}/
            {platform}/
                {tool files}
            {platform}.complete
```

> The version number should follow the format of 1.2.3. The platform
> should either be x86 or x64. The tool files should be the unzipped
> Python version files. The {platform}.complete should be a 0 byte file
> that looks like x86.complete or x64.complete and just signifies the
> tool has been installed in the cache properly.

My test directory structure:

```
$AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY/
    Python/
        3.9.0/
            x64/
                python-3.9.0-amd64.exe
            x64.complete
```

[image]

Now, it works fine on my Self Hosted agent:

[image]

You could refer [the FAQ in this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version?view=azure-devops#how-can-i-configure-a-self-hosted-agent-to-use-this-task) for some more details.

Comment: Thanks Leo. I was able to run the pipeline successfully after configuring as per your screenshot.